# Using a Coroutine with a different return type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

In this function, I wanted to get a random index between 0 and the max size of my list.

I then use that random index so I can pick a random **Node** in the list.

I go through an if statement and check if other **Objects** aren't using that random **Node** I chose.

If no other **Objects** are using that random **Node**, I return that **Node** so the **Object** that called this method can use it.

However, if that **Node** is currently being used by another **Object**, then I wan't to go through the function again, until it gets a **Node** it can use, so I return the function itself.

The result is an overflow error because it's infinitely called (game still works). My first thought was to use a delay (coroutine), so the function doesn't get called so frequently; but the problem is that I need the return type of type **DodgeNode**.

```
public class DodgeLocations : MonoBehaviour {
public List<DodgeNode> nodes;

private DodgeNode randomNode;
private int randomIndex;

public DodgeNode SelectRandomNode(){
    randomIndex = Random.Range(0, nodes.Count);     
    randomNode = nodes[randomIndex];                

    // If the random node is not currently taken (which means if an enemy isn't currently attacking it)
    if (!randomNode.IsTaken ()) {
        // Then the random node is now taken; and other enemies can't touch that node, until the current enemy finishes attacking it    
        randomNode.IsTaken (true);
        return randomNode;
    } else {
        return SelectRandomNode (); // If the node is taken, ask again if there's another node that's free to attack
    }
}
```

}

I brainstormed how it would look like if I used a coroutine and I thought about this.

```
public class DodgeLocations : MonoBehaviour {

public List<DodgeNode> nodes;

private DodgeNode randomNode;
private int randomIndex;

IEnumerator SelectRandomNode(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    randomIndex = Random.Range(0, nodes.Count);     
    randomNode = nodes[randomIndex];                

    // If the random node is not currently taken (which means if an enemy isn't currently attacking it)...
    if (!randomNode.IsTaken ()) {
        // Then the random node is now taken; and other enemies can't touch that node, until the current enemy finishes attacking it    
        randomNode.IsTaken (true);
        yield return randomNode;
    } else {
        yield return SelectRandomNode (); // If the node is taken, ask again if there's another node that's free to attack
    }
}
```

}

Of course this is wrong because I can't return something of type **DodgeNode** with a function that has a return type of **IEnumerator**. However, I still want to use **WaitForSeconds**, so I do need the **IEnumerator** return type.

The problem here is that I want to return a **DodgeNode**, but at the same I need the function to be of return type **IEnumerator** for the **WaitForSeconds** to work.

---

In response to Serlite, here's where I'm using this function (deleted a lot of irrelevant code):

```
public class Bat : Enemy {

private DodgeNode nodeToTarget;               // Node that bat want's to attack
private Vector3 startPoint;                   // Bat's original position
private Vector3 endPoint;                     // Bat's end position

void Start(){
    startCoroutine(AttackPlayerNode());
}

IEnumerator AttackPlayerNode(){
    while (true) {
        nodeToTarget = dodgeLocations.SelectRandomNode();
        endPoint = nodeToTarget.transform.position;   
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveToPoint(startPoint, endPoint));            
        nodeToTarget.IsFree(); // This makes the Node free for other object to use it
    }
}
```

}

---

**Found my "Solution"**

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner programmer/student

I got a piece of paper and tried to write out all of my thought process and ended up with an alternate "solution". Rather than trying to attempt to call **WaitForSeconds** in **SelectRandomNode()**, I decided to make **SelectRandomNode()** return **null** if all **Nodes** were occupied. In the **IEnumerator AttackPlayerNode()**, I have this code:

```
// If the bat doesn't have a node to target
            while(nodeToTarget == null){
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
                nodeToTarget = dodgeLocations.SelectRandomNode();
            }
```

Since I'm returning **null**, this while loop will keep going until a **Node** is open. This will still generate a overflow error (it should I think), but I am now using **WaitForSeconds** which will make the check for an open node less frequent, which prevents the overflow error (to my understanding).

It's probably a very ugly/temporary solution, but I can always go back for optimization in the future! This was haunting me for a full day and am glad I can focus on other elements of my game now.

```
public class DodgeLocations : MonoBehaviour {

public List<DodgeNode> nodes;

private DodgeNode randomNode;

// Returns a randomly chosen node
public DodgeNode SelectRandomNode(){
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, nodes.Count);    
    randomNode = nodes[randomIndex];            

    if (!randomNode.isTaken) {
        randomNode.IsTaken (true);
        return randomNode;
    } else {
        return null; // <--- What was changed
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Bat : Enemy {

private DodgeNode nodeToTarget;               // Node that bat want's to attack
private Vector3 startPoint;                   // Bat's original position
private Vector3 endPoint;                     // Bat's end position

void Start(){
    startCoroutine(AttackPlayerNode());
}

IEnumerator AttackPlayerNode(){
    while (true) {
        // If the bat doesn't have a node to target
        while(nodeToTarget == null){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); // Prevent overflow error
            nodeToTarget = dodgeLocations.SelectRandomNode1();
        }  
        endPoint = nodeToTarget.transform.position;   
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
        yield return StartCoroutine(MoveToPoint(startPoint, endPoint));            
        nodeToTarget.IsFree(); // This makes the Node free for other object to use it
        nodeToTarget = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you plan to use the returned `DodgeNode`?

Comment: I added where I'm using the DodgeNode above. Hope I didn't leave anything out (had to delete a lot of irrelevant code so it isn't clustered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative "solution" and have edited my post above.

**CTRL+F** the following text in bold: **Found my "Solution"**

Comment: You should actually edit your solution into your answer - don't keep it in your question body, because people won't look for it there.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably have already suspected, you're simply doing it wrong.

Using recursion for simple looping is wrong. At worst, your method should instead look something like this:

```
public DodgeNode SelectRandomNode(){

    while (true)
    {
        randomIndex = Random.Range(0, nodes.Count);
        randomNode = nodes[randomIndex];                

        // If the random node is not currently taken (which means if an enemy isn't currently attacking it)
        if (!randomNode.IsTaken ()) {
            // Then the random node is now taken; and other enemies can't touch that node, until the current enemy finishes attacking it    
            randomNode.IsTaken (true);
            return randomNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Better would be to identify eligible nodes *before* you start picking them randomly:

```
public DodgeNode SelectRandomNode(){
    DodgeNode[] eligible = nodes.Where(n => !n.IsTaken()).ToArray();

    randomIndex = Random.Range(0, eligible.Length);
    randomNode = nodes[randomIndex];
    randomNode.IsTaken(true);

    return randomNode;
}
```

Naturally, if it's possible for there to not be any eligible nodes, you'd need to handle that case appropriately. It's not clear from your question what *"appropriate"* would be in this scenario.

It's not clear from the bare example you've provided why you store `randomIndex` as an instance field instead of local variable. If you really need for that to be the index relative to the original collection, you'll need to do a little more work to track the original index (see the `Select()` overload that passes the index along with the enumeration item). But the basic idea is the same.

If you'd rather not recreate the `eligible` array each time you need to pick a node, then you should maintain two collections: the *"not taken"* collection, and the *"taken"* collection. Then you just move nodes from one to the other as needed. If these collections are relatively small (hundreds, or maybe only thousands of items), these can just be regular `List<T>` objects. Larger collections may be costly to remove elements (due to shifting the remaining elements), in which case you might prefer using `LinkedList<T>`.

*Aside: you seem to have declared `IsTaken()` with two overloads, one to return the current value, and one to set it. This is poor design. Ideally, it should just be a property, so you can leave out the `()` that's required for method invocations. If a property doesn't work for you for some reason, then the setting method should have a different name, like `SetIsTaken()`*

Comment: Hmm, in real life a thing inside a bag got its taken flag by getting it out of the bag. So the list sounds more naturally to me :o)

Comment: As a novice programmer, I appreciate your advice for best practices and will also keep all of this in mind (and have made necessary changes to my ugly code)! The recursion for the loop was very silly once I started thinking deeper!